# convert directory names with german 'now' date to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: shell, date, string, conversion

I exported pictures from mac's iPhoto. The directories are named with the date in local naming ("Day. MONTH YYYY"):

```
8. Mai 2013/
13. Juli 2013/
31. Oktober 2014/
```

and some of them with GPS data:

```
Capdepera, 2. Juli 2013/
Stuttgart, 13. Februar 2013/
Marsa Alam, 31. Dezember 2011/
```

I would like to have the directory names like YYYY-MM-DD<.GPS-Data-if-exists> = 2013-07-02.Capdepera

I would separate with `cut -d',' -f1` the GPS-data and with `-f2` the date part (to $DatePart).
In a second step, I would split with the dot '.' the date part to day and moth+year and then take the last 4 digits as Year. After that I'll get

```
GPS="Capdepera"
DAY=02      # fill leading zero is no issue.
MONTH=Juli
YEAR=2013
```

Now, to map month to number, I would create an array like

```
Monate="
Januar=01\n
Februar=02\n
Juli=07\n
"
```

and with `echo -e $Monate | grep $MONTH| cut -d'=' -f2` I got 07 as result. Now I can concat all them to the final directory name to rename it.

My question now is: is there an easier way as I described above? I mean after having with `-f2` the date part in the first step, a date convert like SQL function convert() would give me the result without splitting and array as step between:

convert("$DatePart", +%Y-%m-%d)  => 2013-07-02

Thanks,
Celal

Answer (score 1):

With the perl-based `rename` utitlity, and given a suitably recent version of perl (in particular, older versions of `Time::Piece` don't provide the `use_locale` method that enables parsing of non-English month and day names):

```
$ LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8 rename -n -- '
    BEGIN{use Time::Piece; Time::Piece->use_locale()};
    s/(.*?), (\d+\. \w+ \d+)/Time::Piece->strptime($2,"%d. %B %Y")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d.$1")/e
  ' *,\ */
rename(Capdepera, 2. Juli 2013/, 2013-07-02.Capdepera/)
rename(Marsa Alam, 31. Dezember 2011/, 2011-12-31.Marsa Alam/)
rename(Stuttgart, 13. Februar 2013/, 2013-02-13.Stuttgart/)
```

You can omit the `LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8` assignment if your locale already uses German datetimes. The simpler case (with no GPS data string) is left as an exercise.